# when i create new project on cli i got this error

Tags: angular

```
/ Installing packages...npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3
with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...1eyzg1c6C5x9zUb1lEw42'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-23T06_56_43_955Z-debug.log
× Package install failed, see above.
The Schematic workflow failed. See above.
```

Comment: What is the command that you are running?

Comment: ng new app-start

Comment: can you try to detel this file C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache the retry

Comment: run `npm cache clean --force`
then `npm update`
might work also

Comment: Have you been able to solve the problem?

Comment: yes........................

Comment: How you solved it?

Comment: reinstall  cli with latest version..........

Answer (score 0):

This issue is sometimes related with incomplete installations of the `Angular CLI` or missing downloads while upgrading.

Try reinstalling the `CLI` after cleaning `npm cache`.

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean --force
npm install -g @angular/cli
```